# equivalent for media="all and min-with:900px" in local stylesheet

Tags: css

the project I'm working on has 3 css pages - probably not the best but this is the syntax:

```
<link href="/cg/ui/css/desktop.css"" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:800px)" />
<!-- Tablets -->
<link href="/cg/ui/css/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px)" />
<!-- phones -->
<link href="/cg/ui/css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 599px)" />
```

My question is, is there any way to do the same thing on a local stylesheet with those parameters?  This does not work:

```
<style>
@media "all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px)"{
        /*this was my first guess, if possible but no works*/
}
</style>
```

Thank you, if possible it will make testing much easier!

Comment: Remove the quotes in your example. Try this `@media all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px)`.

Comment: thank you both for your responses, hope this helps the next person!

Answer (score 0):

`@media all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px)`